# How do I blur only a few objects in a scene?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I was creating a scene as the setting for animation when I stumbled across a problem. I want to blur some objects in a scene without blurring others. I would use render layers to do this, but if I do that then the blurred objects end up being displayed over top of some objects that should be in front of it. I would simply add another image layer, but I want to animate the scene and the objects in the foreground will change.

Is there a way that I can make a mask of the image that will allow it to only be displayed in the areas where there is a clear line of sight to it or something similar?

The scene in question:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you test the Focus properties of the camera? So you can decide what object of the scene is in focus

Comment: I didn't, I was under the impression that it would be hard to make only a few objects out of focus while allowing the others to stay in focus by adjusting the camera's focus.